# PHPstorm подключение bitbucket

Tags: phpstorm, bitbucket, mercurial, ssh-key

Я использую репозиторий Mercurial и IDE PHPstorm под Windows.

Установил в **phpstorm** плагин **Bitbucket** и **Mercurial**, импортировал проект в репозиторий. Но почему-то все мои коммиты приходят, как от **анонима**. Подскажите, где это можно сконфигурировать и как заставить использовать его ssh-ключ?

Comment: Попробуйте правой кнопкой на папке, выбрать пункт меню git bash here. Далее как в Убунту.

Comment: У меня не через гит же, а mercurial. У гита как раз прекрасно можно изменить в настройках логин и пароль, а вот у mercurial не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Mercurial.ini файле нужно исправить или добавить `[ui]` секцию:

```
[ui]
username = John Doe <john@example.com>
```

[Документация](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart)

Answer (score 0):

```
так-как все мануалы по гиту в основном для убунты
```

Это шутка? Да?

```
Но почему то все мои коммиты приходят как от анонима
```

Под кем подключаешься от того и коммиты!

**//upd**

Все ведь можно сделать через консоль, неправда ли?

```
$ git config --global user.name "имя"
$ git config --global user.email "Почта"
```

Она и в винде есть.

Comment: Да, я очень большой шутник. Если располагаете информацией, то поделитесь, пожалуйста. При первом подключении у меня запросило логин и пароль. Я вошел, но комитит от анонима.  Вот я и спрашиваю, где можно редактировать "под кем подключаешься".

Comment: Это команды для гита. Увы, вопрос удалить не могу